# UK visit visa refusal: insufficient financial documentation

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

My friend applied for general visit visa from Kampala to UK but the officer refused his visa. The reason I'm going to mention:

> 1: I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not
>   satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph V4.2 and V4.3 of
>   Appendix V: immigration rules for Visitors because.
>
> 1. In order to be able to make a decision on whether or not to grant you entry clearance in this category I have taken into account your
>      stated circumstances in Nigeria, the reasons for your visit,and your
>      proposed travel arrangements. You have declared that you are a self
>      employed and that you earn US$2,500 (£1,644.73 using an exchange rate
>      of US$1.52 to the £1) per month from all sources after tax. You have
>      stated that you have no further paid jobs or occupations.   In support
>      of your application you have submitted business registration documents
>      and a bank statement in the name of Atlas Motors U limited. I am not
>      satisfied that these  documents are an accurate  reflection of your
>      personal circumstances because;  this statement is for a business
>      account and represents funds used for the activities and running of
>      the business and is no satisfactory evidence that these funds are
>      available to support anything else. Furthermore these funds do not
>      necessarily reflect an individual's personal financial
>      circumstances,even if that individual is the sole owner of the
>      company. I am not satisfied therefore that this bank statement
>      accurately reflects your personal circumstances; neither am I
>      satisfied that the indicated funds will be available for your
>      exclusive use. You have not provided any satisfactory evidence of
>      other funds being available to you, or of your own personal and
>      financial circumstances.
>
>    I must take into your account your personal and economic
>      circumstances in Uganda when coming to my decision. However given the
>      statements you have made and the documentary evidence you have
>      presented to support your application I am not satisfied that your
>      circumstances, coupled with your reasons for wishing to travel to
>      United Kingdom, are such that you intend a genuine visit and have
>      sufficient intention to leave the United Kingdom at the end of your
>      visit. Nor am I satisfied that the funds presented will be available
>      to you as stated given the concerns raised. I am not satisfied that
>      you are genuinely seeking entry that you intend to leave the United
>      Kingdom at the end of the period of the visit. I am therefore not
>      satisfied that you meet the requirements of Paragraph4.2(a) and (c).
>      Nor am I satisfied that you will be maintained and accommodated in the
>      UK without recourse to work or public funds.
>
> Your application for a visit visa has been refused under paragraph
>   V4.2(e).

Now please read all this and answer me what should we have to do further for next application.
There is no right of appeal or right to administrative review.

Comment: Um, it seems you're not even saying which country your friend (?) applied for a visa FOR. And even if you do reveal this, you probably won't be able to get any useful advice here unless you also, _at a minimum_ quote the refusal notice in your question. (Using some punctuation and capitalization would also help motivating people to spend some effort helping you, but _first_ you need to give them enough information to go by).

Comment: Are you the sponsor? Applied where?  I assume that your 'friend' (?) applied to the BHC Kampala  for a Standard Visitor Visa? Without seeing the refusal notice and more detail you won't get a quality answer because too much is missing.  Please go to http://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/60455/edit and provide the refusal notice and more detail, thanks.  Close voting as 'unclear'

Comment: @mkennedy, Chrome seems to have a drag-n-drop feature for images; when you click on the 'insert image', you get a dialog with a drop zone on it.  Try it!

Comment: Your 'friend' appears to have submitted financial documents of the business. If he is the owner and sole proprietor, how much is he paying himself in wages? That is what he should have reported, along with proof of that income (bank statements of the individual, not of the business.)

Comment: If now we applied for a medical treatment visit visa then it will b effect on our application  or not ..as already we applied for gernal visit visa.

Answer (score 6):

You are self-employed and claimed a monthly after tax income of USD 2,500 from your own company. To support your claim you sent the company registration documents (that was fine) and the company bank statements (also fine). They replied that your documents were insufficient because they could not tie everything out and there was no evidence that the money was actually available to you.  Self-employed applicants are more complex because they need to be sure that the income was lawfully gained and that the balances are actually available (i.e., corporate and personal taxes have been paid).

What they will want to see in this type of situation is...

1. Company bank statements showing a regular dividend stream along with
   nominal salary payments into your personal account; and
2. Personal bank statements that tie out to the dividend/salary
   streams; and
3. The formation documents showing your ownership of the company; and
4. Corporate and personal tax vouchers for the dividend/salary streams; and
5. Evidence that your after tax earnings is actually USD 2,500 as claimed.

Sending these things will give them the needed level of comfort that your circumstances are as claimed and that said funds are both legal and actually available to you.

The importance of regular funds movement between the various accounts cannot be understated.  Sometimes self-employed applicants in Nigeria and elsewhere avoid the rigmarole of dividends/salary and segregated bank accounts because the funds movements can create both corporate and personal tax liabilities.  If this is the case with you, then you would need to undergo a period of compliance, say 6 - 12 months before having enough documentation to successfully apply again.

For the refusal specifics, they *mentioned* V 4.2 (a) & (c), suggesting that you were looking for a chance to go underground once you arrived in the UK, but they actually *got* you on V 4.2 (e)...

> must have sufficient funds to cover all reasonable costs in relation
>   to their visit without working or accessing public funds. This
>   includes the cost of the return or onward journey, any costs relating
>   to dependants, and the cost of planned activities such as private
>   medical treatment.

This would indicate that if you clean up your company/personal situation, you have a chance to be successful.  The refusal notice does not mention any other show-stoppers, but success cannot be guaranteed without seeing all of your other stuff.

---

**Now please read all this and answer me what should we have to do further for next application.**

1. Most needed is to show a change of circumstances.  You can examine
   the 5 items listed above and take the steps needed to bring them
   about. Usually 6 - 12 months of evidence should be sufficient, but
   of course you can apply any time, there is no required interval
   between successive applications.  Patience is key.
2. You also need to study [the guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf) about the other evidence
   that they want to see.  The BHC in Kampala can be tough players
   sometimes and it's better to get everything spit-spot to avoid more
   refusals.
3. Finally [study the rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) to cover yourself for any other grounds
   for refusal.

**There is no right of appeal or right to administrative review.**

Yes, the government believes, reasonably so, that tourism is not a human right; it's cheaper and more expedient to submit a fresh application (as long as the applicant's circumstances have significantly changed).

**should we have to apply now through any solicitor or not.**

It is not a requirement to use a solicitor, but I have it in mind that more applicants would be successful if they were to instruct a solicitor.  The solicitor should be a member of the [UK Law Society](http://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/?Pro=True), avoid sham operators in Africa.

Comment: thaknx alot dear...should we have to apply now through any solicitor or not..

Comment: @AliButt answer updated, fair point

Comment: thax.alot for ur cooperation 

Comment: will u please tell me that he have to show his bank statements or not..