# UK visitor visa rejected for my parents. Please help

Tags: visas, uk

My parents applied for a UK visitor visa to visit my husband and me in the UK. We both have work permits in the UK and are working for an Indian IT company. We gave all the documents in support and mentioned that we would be sponsoring their visit to UK.

Documents provided:

1. Invitation letter from me to them.
2. My bank statements.
3. My employment letter.
4. My house's lease agreement.
5. My father's bank statements.
6. My father's house and shop's registry documents.

My father is a businessman and he showed a yearly income of 500,000 INR per year and a closing balance in his account is 191,000.

It seems the visa officer misread the yearly income as monthly income. Below is the response in the refusal letter.

> I am satisfied that your sponsor is legally resident in UK and willing to accommodate you and pay your visit costs. However I must consider your own personal and financial circumstances while accessing your application. You have stated that you are self employed as the owner of ******* and your income is INR 500,000 (5,490 pounds at Oanda rate of exchange) per *month* and that you have other unspecified income from savings. Your bank account statement shows a current balance of INR 197,368 (2,167 pounds). You have not provided any evidence of your business in the form of a separate bank statement, accounts or your company and personal Income tax returns. The deposits noted on the statements do not concur with your income. I am therefore not satisfied that you have demonstrated an accurate account of your employment, income and circumstances.

Can you please help? what should we do now if we want our parents to visit us? Shall we wait for some time and reapply or reapply immediately? And what more documents should be added so that they don't reject this time?

Comment: You should address the specific issues raised in the refusal letter.

Comment: While there is the error, monthly not annual income, looking at correctly means a much lower income and, more importantly lots of missing information that was not provided. Regardless of sponsorship, applicants must show that they qualify on their own and having a sponsor often raises the bar. Look at [this canonical](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) and [this response](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60455/uk-visit-visa-refusal-insufficient-financial-documentation)

Comment: And I should have said welcome to TSE. We do ask that a copy of the refusal letter be uploaded, personal info redacted, to see the ECO statements and the section(s) under which it was refused. In many cases, there are comprehensive answers here that respond, and a new question closed as a duplicate.

Comment: VTC: OP has not returned since asking the question, nor added a scan of the refusal, making it difficult to either respond or point to a TSE duplicate.